# unexpected end of regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.3

I want to get only the file name with extension from the path:

```
C:\\Users\\anandada\\workspace\\MyTestProject\\src\\OpenTest.c
```

The statement below,

```py
fileName = re.match("[^\\]*.c$", fileName)
```

gives error:

> unexpected end of regular expression

I am using python 3.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *double* the doubled escapes *again*, *or* use a raw string instead:

```
fileName = re.match("[^\\\\]*.c$",fileName)
```

or

```
fileName = re.match(r"[^\\]*.c$",fileName)
```

otherwise first Python, then the regular expression compiler will interpret those backslashes, resulting in the `]` being escaped:

```
>>> print("[^\\]*.c$")
'[^\]*.c$'
```

Also see the [*Blackslash Plague* section](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague) of the Python Regex HOWTO.

Next, you need to be aware that `re.match` *anchors to the start of the string*. You'll probably want to use `re.search()` instead here. See the [*`match()` vs. `search()` section*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#match-versus-search):

> The `match()` function only checks if the RE matches at the beginning of the string while `search()` will scan forward through the string for a match. It’s important to keep this distinction in mind.

You may also want to escape the `.` in the `.c` part; `.` matches any character, so `foobaric` would also match; the `i` would satisfy the `.` pattern.

The `re.match()` and `re.search()` functions return a [*match object*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), not the matched part of the string. You'll have to extract that part explicitly:

```
fileName = re.search(r'[^\\]*\.c$', fileName).group()
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> fileName = 'C:\\Users\\anandada\\workspace\\MyTestProject\\src\\OpenTest.c'
>>> re.search(r'[^\\]*\.c$', fileName).group()
'OpenTest.c'
```

Comment: Yes, and `[^\]*.c$` isn't a valid regex pattern as the `]` is escaped and the construct `[` is not balanced.

Comment: i think he wants only `OpenTest.c`

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't use a raw string. The double backslash is interpreted as an escape for the closing square bracket. You need to write:

```
fileName = re.match(r"[^\\]*.c$", fileName)
```

with the raw string format `\\` is seen as a literal backslash as expected.